# How can I create a PHP class where one of its functions it to clone itself?

Tags: php, clone, this

Basically, I need to store past versions of this object in its current state in an array. Something like:

```
 public class MyClass{
     $n = 0;
     $array = array()

     storeOldVersion(){
          $this->array[] = clone $this;
     }
 }
```

I know I do something like "clone $this->n", but how can I literally clone the MyClass object itself, and store it into an array the MyClass object holds?

Thanks

Comment: What's wrong with your above code?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What you proposed actually works, except you had some incorrect code. The following version works:

```
class MyClass{
     protected $n = 0;
     public $array = array();

     public function storeOldVersion(){
          $this->array[] = clone $this;
          $this->n = 2;
     }
 }

$a = new MyClass();
$a->storeOldVersion();

echo "<pre>";
var_dump( $a ); // retuns class with n = 2
var_dump( $a->array ); // return array with one class having n = 0
```

**A word of warning though**

If you call storeOldVersion() more than once, as is, it will recursively clone the "array" that contains other clones and your object could get pretty massive exponentially. You should probably unset the array variable from the clone before storing it in the array..

e.g.

```
$clone = clone $this;
$clone->array = array();
$this->array[] = $clone;
```

Comment: i actually have both variables as private...does that matter?

Comment: doesn't matter. You should use accessor methods anyway. e.g. $a->getOldVersions(); etc.. I made it public only so that I could dump it to illustrate the example.

Comment: @user954912 - No because the class itself is accessing them. However, note that storing the previous versions inside the class itself means the arrays holding them are cloned along with `n`.

Comment: should I be using accessor methods when I'm within the "storeOldVersion()" function? 

or only when I'm using an instance of the MyClass object?

Comment: @user954912 I'd recommend using getters and setters both inside and outside of your class. It makes your code more readable and gives you more flexibility for refactoring.

Answer (score 1):

You can also try serialization for complicated objects. It will store the object as a string. After all you can unserialize string to object with the past state.

http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.serialization.php

Comment: If the history is removed before serializying, I think it's a good to have serialization in mind.

Answer (score 0):

With a little cleanup, your code works.  However, you probably want to clean out the `$array` of old versions in the old versions you store, otherwise you're going to end up with a huge recursive mess on your hands.

```
<?php
class MyClass{
     private $n = 0;
     private $array = array();

     public function storeOldVersion(){
          $clone = clone $this;
          $clone->array = null;
          $this->array[] = $clone;
     }
 }


$c = new MyClass();
$c->storeOldVersion();
var_dump($c);
```